# How to set a function to work only if i have not click Delete Button.?

Tags: jquery, keyboard

I want a `function or event` only to work if I ***have not*** click <kbd>Delete</kbd> key or  <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key button on keybord.?

I have tried some methods but it didn't work amoung them i have posting one.

```
$('body').on('keyup','.myClass',function(event){
     if(!event.keyCode == 8 || !event.keyCode == 46){
         console.log('Not Deleted');
     }
 });
```

if I use this `if` condition removing the `!` from the `!event` in the code and use `else` condition am getting the `console.log` there But I don't want to use `else` for this, so any help would be appreciated. Thank You for advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!event.keyCode` is converting the value into a boolean. And `true !== 8`.

You should try

```
 if (event.keyCode !== 8 && event.keyCode !== 46) {
 ...
 }
```

Comment: why are we using `!==` instead of `!=` ?

Comment: In this example, it might not matter, but in general it is intended to use the === or !== comparisons due to type coercion. eg "3" == 3, but "3" !== 3

Answer (score 1):

Change your a little like this:

```
$('body').on('keyup','.myClass',function(event){
     if(event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 46){
         console.log('Not Deleted');
         // Your further code goes here.....
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('keyup','.myClass',function(event){
 if(event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46){
     return;
 }
 // Your code goes here
});
```